# Has anybody immigrating to France been asked a criminal record from their home country?

Tags: france

I want to ask this question because my home country asks for the name of the institution to which it should be addressed, and it can take over six months to have it issued by the Ministry of the Interior (same as the Home Office) and then apostilled.

Has anybody been required to produce a criminal record? By whom? To what institution should it be addressed?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand: Who wants to send what where? Do you want to know if that's a requirement to get a French visa or residence permit? Have you asked some institution in your home country for a copy of your criminal record before knowing if you would actually require one? Have you been asked for one by the French authorities? What kind of French visa or permit are you hoping to get? To my knowledge, nothing like this is required in France.